# HTC ONE X Custom ROM Issue

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, htc-one-x, unbricking

I tried to install a custom ROM on my htc one X without making any backup. My new custom ROM did not installed correctly. It is just showing X type logo of custom ROM after htc splash screen. I can go to hboot, fastboot and recovery menus. I can also access the memory card. My problem is that I do not know how can I add new custom ROM on memory card so I can install it. Please help.

Comment: Please post the exact steps you've taken to install the ROM.

Comment: In most cases you can simply copy the corresponding ZIP file to the card (e.g. using a card reader attached to your PC), and install it from within the recovery menu. To find different ROMs, please check with [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575), or e.g. directly on [CyanogenMod.com](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) which I know works this way.

Comment: @Izzy : I am using htc one x. It has no external memory card. When I connect my device with PC, it do not show device. So I am stuck on how to add ZIP file in card. :(

Comment: @Chahk I followed that ROM and tutorial http://wccftech.com/root-htc-one-x-endeavoru-to-aosp-android-4-2-2/

Comment: If you can boot into recovery, adb should recognize your phone. Verify this by issuing the following command in command prompt: `adb devices` It should return the serial # of your phone. If it doesn't - you need to install USB drivers. Now using the "adb push" command you can copy the necessary files to the phone: `adb push <path-to-zip> /sdcard` Now you can try flashing the phone again as per instructions.

Comment: @Chak thank you. When I wrote command adb devices. It shows my device but with offline status. When I try to execute push command it says  " device is offline". I don't know why it is showing my device offline. You have any idea about that? Thanks

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

yesterday I had the same problem,and finally I found the solution.

1. Flash TWRP recovery on your one X, and power off.
2. Then Connect your phone to your PC by using usb cable
3. Boot into twrp recovery select mount & storage on twrp menu and the
   select Mount USB Storage,after doing this your PC should see your phone as USB storage.
4. Copy your rom file into sdcard on your PC.
5. Disconnect the phone from PC,reboot your phone into bootloader and
   then run twrp recovery.
6. Before flashing rom full wipe is recommended to avoid problems, so full wipe by twrp recovery or by fastboot commands (**fastboot erase cache**)
7. Flash compatible boot.img by using fastboot commands (**fastboot flash boot bootfile.img**)
8. Full wipe your device
9. Then flash the rom.zip by using twrp,that's all.